# GWT with Google App Engine - Upload a file

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload, blobstore, gwtupload

How can I upload a file using GWT with GAE?
I found GWTUpload and [AppEngineUploadAction](http://gwtupload.googlecode.com/svn/site/apidocs/gae/gwtupload/server/gae/AppEngineUploadAction.html) class, but it can't write to the file system.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no file system on App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE runs a restricted java environment, and writing to the file-system is forbidden.

You have to select one way to store that data in GAE, gwtupload supports 3 ways to store that data in server, and it offers 3 servlets:

- `AppEngineUploadAction` which will store the uploaded data in [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/). In this case the data will be lost unless you save it somewhere. This is thought as a temporary repository to process the data and send back to the client etc.
- `BlobstoreUploadAction` to persist data using google [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) service.
- `FilesApiUploadAction` used to store data in the google [cloud storate](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/)

The client part of gwtupload works with all of them, but there are some issues, mainly if you dont have a bill account, google can interrupt the request. Progress doesnt work well, although new version of gwtupload plans to have progress based in html5.

Comment: Thank you. 
Maybe, i don't need to use GAE. I will do it withoud google app engine sdk using UploadAction...